# Nuxeo Maven installation Error

Tags: nuxeo

Hi I have installed the nuxeo application source through nuxeo github. but while installing the maven dependencies i got the following Error.

Please Find The Error Below.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project nuxeo-launcher-commons: There are test failures.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] Please refer to D:\nuxeolocalcode\nuxeo\nuxeo-runtime\nuxeo-launcher-commons\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

Please Help me solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version have you downloaded? Were you able to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with -DskipTests

```
mvn -DskipTests install
```

https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/getting-the-nuxeo-source-code/